# Facebook - Custom notifications text using Graph api custom stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm using the request dialog in my website. If a user logged in using Facebook, He will be presented with the dialog to invite his friends to try the website.

Currently the notification text is `XXXX sent you a request` I want to change it to `XXXX has joined yyy.com`.

From what I read it's not possible to do this. But while reading the documentation I've noticed that one can use graph custom stories inside the notifications.

I've created the request dialog using this code :

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "Take a look at Our site."
});
```

Is that possible to achieve what I want to do ? If so, How is it done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible unfortunately, for two reasons:

1. Facebook doesn't allow actions like "installed" or "joined" with Open Graph (see their [submission process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process)
2. App requests are for games, not general websites.

Your best bet for "invites" would be the [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog).